# how to repeat song 5-time in mediaplayer android

Tags: android, media-player

I develop one app which based on media player. there are three button name 2,5,10.
Each button have event which repeat song 2-tim, 5-time, 10-time.
But made but i don't know how to get count value of repeat song using mediaplayer.setLooping(true).
can anybody help me to count this value.

media player code

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(musicurl);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

and onclick event

```
          btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = 0;
            if(i<2{
            mp.setLooping(true)
            i++
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have same problem. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Count here and restart if required.
        }});
```